# Creating a URL object with a relative path

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am creating a Swing application with a `JEditorPane` that should display an HTML file named `url1.html` stored locally in the *page* folder in the root folder of the project.

I have instantiated the following String object

```
final String pagePath = "./page/";
```

and in order to be displayed by the `JEditorPane` pane I have created the following URL object:

```
URL url1 = new URL("file:///"+pagePath+"url1.html");
```

However when the `setPage()` method is called with the created URL object as a parameter:

```
pagePane.setPage(url1);
```

it throws me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error.

It seems that there is something wrong with the way `url1` has been constructed. Anyone knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to find an absolute path to `url1.html` make an object of `java.io.File` on it, and then use `toURI().toURL()` combination:

```
URL url1 = (new java.io.File(absolutePathToHTMLFile)).toURI().toURL();
```

Assuming if the current directory is the root of `page`, you can pass a relative path to `File`:

```
URL url1 = (new java.io.File("page/url1.html")).toURI().toURL();
```

or

```
URL url1 = (new java.io.File(new java.io.File("page"), "url1.html")).toURI().toURL();
```

But this will depend on where you run the application from. I would make it taking the root directory as a command-line argument if it is the only configurable option for the app, or from a configuration file, if it has one.

The another solution is to put the html file as a resource into the jar file of your application.

Answer (score 1):

To load a resource from the classpath (as khachik mentioned) you can do the following:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("page/url1.html");
```

or from a static context:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("page/url1.html");
```

So in the case above, using a Maven structure, the HTML page would be at a location such as this:

```
C:/myProject/src/main/resources/page/url1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

```
URL url = new URL("file", "", pagePath+"url1.html");
```

I believe by concatenating the whole string, you are running into problems. Let me know, if that helped